# What is the difference of "take the test" and "do the test"?

Tags: word-choice

Most of the cases I read is "Take the test".

But today I found an Australian government [website](https://www.health.gov.au/initiatives-and-programs/national-bowel-cancer-screening-program/getting-a-bowel-screening-test/how-to-do-the-bowel-screening-test) saying do the test:

> You do the test in the privacy of your own home.

And [another one](https://www.cancer.nsw.gov.au/dothetest/)

> Do the test when it comes in the post.

Is this saying only works in Australia? What is the difference between Take the test? Can anyone explain in detail. I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are correct. I think there are subtle differences between "take" and "do".

Wherever "perform" would be suitable, **do** can be substituted.

> A chemist might **do/perform** a test to find out what kind of acid is
> in the test tube.
>  A doctor might **do/perform** a blood test.
> If they send you the equipment you can **do/perform** the Covid test
> at home.

Notice how *take* doesn't work in those cases:
If the chemist *takes* a test, he sits it.
The doctor *takes* the blood, not the test.
If you *take* a Covid test at home it tests your *knowledge* of the disease.

When your **ability** is to be tested you **take** a test (or you *sit* an exam):

> You **take** your driving test
>  You **take** a French language
> test.
>  A website where you can test your reflexes might say,
> '**Take** the test!'

Note that *perform* wouldn't be suitable in these. So **take** is better than **do**.

You neither *take* nor *do* an eye test or a blood test. You simply *have* one or *go for* one. (Or undergo one!)

The trouble is we tend to use *have/had/do/did* informally for *everything!*